# Fechar conexão em outro método

Tags: java

Tenho uma classe chamada `JavaConnect` e nela tenho dois métodos: `ConnectDB` e `DesconnectDb`.

Classe da conexão:

```
public class JavaConnect {

    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnectDb(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/NetBeansProjects/Controller_workshop/dbControlworkshop.sqlite");
            /*JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexao realizada");*/
            return conn;      
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void DesconnectDb(Connection conn){  
        try{  
            if(conn != null) {  
                conn.close();  
            }  
        }catch (SQLException e){ 
        }  
    }
}
```

Até ai entendi mais ou menos as funcionalidades. Porem preciso inciar elas dentro do JFrame.

Codigo abaixo para auxiliar a entender meu erro:

```
public void PreencherTabela(String Sql){
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String [] colunas = new String []{"ID","NOME","RG","CPF","RUA","TELEFONE","NUMERO","BAIRRO","CIDADE","ESTADO","CEP"};
    JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
    JavaConnect.DesconnectDb(conn);
}
```

Quando chamo o metodo `DesconnectDb`, o "conn" fica errado e me apresenta o erro na lateral da seguinte maneira:

> cannot find symbol

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `Connection` é *auto-closeable*, isto é, você pode usar um block `try-with-resources` para finalizar automaticamente.

Além disso, existem outras coisas que dá pra melhorar no código, tal como:

- Inicialize a classe *driver* apenas uma vez, por exemplo num bloco de inicialização estático.
- Não retorne `null` do método de conexão após mostrar o erro para o usuário, caso contrário o programa vai gerar outra exceção `NullPointerException` logo depois, ao tentar utilizar a referência `conn` retornada. Neste caso, é melhor deixar a `SQLException` ser lançada e tratar na chamada.

Vejamos como fica um exemplo ajustado:

```
public class JavaConnect {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); //inicializa apenas uma vez
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLite Driver não encontrado!");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/NetBeansProjects/Controller_workshop/dbControlworkshop.sqlite");
    }
}
```

Então basta usar da seguinte forma:

```
public class QualquerOutraClasse {
    public void qualquerOutroMetodo() {

        try (Connection conn = JavaConnect.getConnection()) {
            conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from tabela");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao acessar o banco de dados: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

## Alternativa usando lâmbda

Uma implementação alternativa em Java 8 ou superior poderia facilitar ainda mais, se usar um lâmbda para executar o SQL.

Exemplo:

```
public class JavaConnect {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLite Driver não encontrado!");
        }
    }

    public interface OperacaoNoBanco {
        void executar(Connection connection) throws SQLException;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/NetBeansProjects/Controller_workshop/dbControlworkshop.sqlite");
    }

    public static void executar(final OperacaoNoBanco operacaoNoBanco) {
        try (Connection conn = JavaConnect.getConnection()) {
            operacaoNoBanco.executar(getConnection());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao acessar o banco de dados: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

E então pode usar o novo método `executar` assim:

```
class QualquerOutraClasse {
    public void qualquerOutroMetodoUsandoLambda() {
        JavaConnect.executar(con -> {
            con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from tabela");
        });
    }
}
```

Enfim, chamando o método `executar`, você pode executar qualquer operação no banco. Estando confinada ao lâmbda, qualquer erro será propriamente tratado dentro daquele método. O uso fica bem simples e seguro, sem risco de esquecer de fechar a conexão.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é o escopo da variável `conn`, ela só existe dentro da classe `JavaConnect`. Se você quer passar a variável apenas para fechar a conexão, o método `PreencherTabela()` precisa estar dentro da mesma classe ou criar uma variável de conexão local dentro deste método, recebendo uma conexão como retorno do seu método `ConnectDb()`(como foi apresentado na outra resposta), ou simplesmente delegar a responsabilidade unicamente para a classe `JavaConnect`:

```
public class JavaConnect {

    Connection conn = null;

    public static void ConnectDb() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/NetBeansProjects/Controller_workshop/dbControlworkshop.sqlite");
            /*JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexao realizada");*/
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void DesconnectDb() {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

E dentro do método basta chamar os métodos quando forem necessários:

```
public void PreencherTabela(String Sql){
    ArrayList dados = new ArrayList();
    String [] colunas = new String []{"ID","NOME","RG","CPF","RUA","TELEFONE","NUMERO","BAIRRO","CIDADE","ESTADO","CEP"};
    JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
    JavaConnect.DesconnectDb();
}
```

Lembrando que essa solução pode ser boa se sua aplicação foi standalone, e não possui concorrência de conexões.

Comment: Chamaar this.conn não vai dar erro em um método estático? Funcionaria se fosse uma variável do objeto, nesse caso JavaConnect deveria ser instanciado

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza é verdade, é o hábito hehe. Vou alterar

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, sua explicação me ajudou a entender o problema!

Comment: Eu entendo que a resposta é útil e ajuda, mas para quem acessar esta questão no futuro, é bom saber que esta não é uma estrutura recomendada para acessar o banco de dados, pois pode facilmente ocorrer o caso de não fechar adequadamente a conexão. Minha resposta propõe dois mecanismos mais seguros.

Answer (score 3):

O erro ocorrre por quê `conn` só existe dentro da classe `JavaConnect`.

Tente:

```
Connection conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
JavaConnect.DesconnectDb(conn);
```

Dessa forma você consegue acessar o retorno do método.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, realmente eu não sabia desta questão!

Comment: Eu entendo que a resposta é útil e ajuda, mas para quem acessar esta questão no futuro, é bom saber que esta não é uma estrutura recomendada para acessar o banco de dados, pois pode facilmente ocorrer o caso de não fechar adequadamente a conexão. Minha resposta propõe dois mecanismos mais seguros.